# First run,use ./bin/confluent start to start kafka failed

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

when I download latests confluent to use,I find I can run...

```
$ ./bin/confluent start

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.AV6gmvzx
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
-Kafka failed to start
kafka is [DOWN]
Cannot start Schema Registry, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment
```

And the enviroment is:

```
$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

$ mvn -v

Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /apps/svr/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /apps/svr/jdk1.8.0_162/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

what's the problem?

Comment: It's difficult to help without more details -- you didn't share information why Kafka failed to start.  What does `bin/confluent log kafka` show you, for example? What's your OS (I suppose Linux from the above)? Which version of Confluent Platform, v4.1? Have you installed Confluent Platform from zip/tarball or via RPM/DEB packages?

Comment: Did you stop the previous install before trying to run the new version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was a local Confluent run .
This happens because Kafka internally uses hostnames instead of IP addresses .

Check if  **hostname** matches the hostname of **127.0.0.1** in `/etc/hosts`

In my case the result on running command **>hostname** in terminal was not matching

127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts file and I ended up updating hostname from localhost to the new hostname